# stdlib Pathname#relative_path_from does not support mixed directory separators on windows

Tags: ruby, windows

The support for mixing backslashes and forward slashes in the pathname module in the standard library seems to be broken on windows

```
require 'pathname'
base = Pathname.new("c:\\")
filepath = Pathname.new("c:/foo/bar/file.ext")
base.relative_path_from(filepath)
```

raises `ArgumentError: different prefix: "c:\\" and "c:/foo/bar/file.ext"`

Changing filepath to contain backslashes fixes the problem

```
filepath = Pathname.new("c:\\foo\\bar\\file.ext")
base.relative_path_from(filepath)
```

`=> #<Pathname:../../..>`